# No new variables from InsertOne mongodb golang after adding TTL

Tags: mongodb, go

So i have created a TTL and upon adding it this new error pops up:

no new variables on left side of := : _, err := c.Coll.InsertOne(c.Ctx, url)

code:

```golang
    indexOptions := options.Index().SetExpireAfterSeconds(int32(newUrl.Expires) * 24 * 3600)

    _, err := c.Coll.Indexes().CreateOne(c.Ctx,
        mongo.IndexModel{
            Keys:    bson.M{"exp": 1},
            Options: indexOptions},
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    url := newUrl.IntoURL()

    _, err := c.Coll.InsertOne(c.Ctx, url)
    return url, err
```

### Solved, look in comments!

Comment: `err` is already declared in the line where `CreateOne` method is invoked. You are re-declaring it again in same scope in the line `InsertOne`, with the use of `:=`. Change it to just `=` i.e. `_, err = c.Coll.InsertOne(c.Ctx, url)`